# Guidance in creating a dependency property in WPF/MVVMLight application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

I have a WPF/MVVMLight application. My main view/viewmodel has a data grid with code behind in the viewmodel. I recently decided I'd like
this datagrid in a 2nd view, one view is live data, one view is showing history of same data. I don't want to duplicate this code in two places so I decided to create a usercontrol with a viewmodel and move the appropriate datagrid/code to the usercontrol.

Here is the issue/question: I would like to set the usercontrol->datagrid->itemsource to a property in my main viewmodel. I've seen some examples where people create dependencyproperties but I'm not sure how to handle this because I can't inherit DependencyObject in my viewmodel because it already inherits ViewModelBase (from mvvm light), so I can't use GetValue/SetValue as seen below. I'm very new to this so I may be missing something very obvious. While looking for solutions to my problem I'm seeing that MVVM Light has some messaging functionality, would this be a better way to approach this? Is there a better approach to this than what i'm taking? Thanks for any guidance.

Example not pulled from my code, just used to show the GetValue/SetValue that I can't figure out how to use because I can't inherit DependencyObject.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public static DependencyProperty MyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridItemSource", typeof(EventData), typeof(MyViewModel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    public EventData GridItemSource
    {
        get { return (EventData)GetValue(MyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyProperty, value); }
    }
```

--- Attemping to be more clear in what i'm hoping to achieve..

Below is an example of the datagrid in my usercontrol. My user control has a VM with code behind with properties for the bindings you see below and some additional code related to the context menu.

The issue i'm trying to resolve is how to set the usercontrol datagrid itemsource now that it is in a usercontrol that is nested in my main view, and eventually will be nested in one more view. My mainview has a ObservableCollection with the data I want the usercontrol/datagrid/itemsource set to. My thinking was I could create a dependency property in the usercontrol that my main view could use to set the source.

So in my main view where I add the user control i want to do something like this:

```
<Views:MyUserControl SomePropertyInUserControl="{Binding MyObservableCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In my user control view:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding DataGridSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" HeadersVisibility="All" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="lbMain" ItemsSource="{Binding MonitorEventItems, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuEventList,Mode=Default}"/>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding EventDateTime}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event Type" Binding="{Binding EventType}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folder/File" Binding="{Binding FFType}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding EventFileFolderName}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Path" Binding="{Binding EventFileFolderFullPath}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: dependency properties don't belong in  a viewmodel, they already implement inotifypropertychanged which is kindof a dependency property light.

Comment: DPs are fine in VMs, if they make sense there. This doesn't make much sense.  It isn't clear to me at all what your goal is... Are you trying to bind your ViewModel to a UserControl's ViewModel? Because if you are... ***no.*** Your UC shouldn't have a VM.  It should expose DependencyProperties on its surface to which your ViewModel's bind against.  That may be your real issue.

Comment: I updated my question hoping to be more clear in what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29305125/684042). (Note: does not use dependency properties) Example handling this with EventHandler and using MVVM Light Messaging. Other possible solutions/answers in thread as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use dependency properties in view models. Their main difference from ordinary properties is to be settable by bindings, styles, animations, etc., which you do not need in a view model.

Instead, create a property that raises the `PropertyChanged` event of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which is implemented by the ViewModelBase class. In addition, use `ObservableCollection` as property type, to notify about changes in the Items collection.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> items;

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```